# explanation of the output of the following program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf(5+"good morning");/*need explanation for this line
return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is - morning
can anyone explain how?

Comment: Welcome to C, we have obfuscation here. Now try to explain what this does: `printf((char*restrict const const const const)??<&5??("good morning":>%>);`.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype of `printf`

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Here `format` is a type of `const char*` and point to address of first element of string literal. When you pass `5+"Good morning"` in `printf`, what you are really passing is the memory address of the string plus `5`. The plus `5` means printing will start `5` `chars` beyond the start of the string, and the space after the word "Good",counts as a char.

Answer (score 1):

when you call with `5+"good morning"` parameter is converted to pointer. That means there is string constant `"good morning"` stored somewhere in the executable and compiler pass its pointer. something like this:

```
const char txt[]="good morning\0";
printf(5+txt);
```

So the `printf` will obtain the evaluated pointer `txt+5` which bypassed first 5 characters in the string (as one char is single BYTE and single memory address on 8bit WORD addressing machines).

Answer (score 0):

> The output of the program is - morning

```
printf(5+"good morning");
```

prints the string inside the `" "`, ***overpassing*** the first five characters. So the first four characters `g`, `o`, `o`, `d` and the fifth character, the space, will be overpassed and the rest of the string will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

`Printf()` method, is used to print the text in ()

It prints only "morning" and 5+ bypassed the initial 5 characters that is "g" "o" "o" "d" and a " " (space)